Can't snap to bezier path intersection on Inkscape
So I have two open Bezier paths drawn in Inkscape, and I'm trying to combine them by their intersection. 
I figured that I could add a node to their intersection on both paths. But even though the handle, shown with the X, is at the right place, when I double-click, the node is created away from the X. How do I properly snap to the path intersection?

I'm using Inkscape 1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25)

For whatever reason, snapping to path intersections doesn't seem to work as expected when adding a node. This could be considered a bug or even just a missing feature.  There is an issue already reported on Inkscape's GitLab, and it has been marked as a feature request.  There is a post on that same GitHub page which says it's possible if you don't actually hover over the path, and then double click, but I have found this difficult to do. It worked once for me, then it didn't work the next time.
Some other possible solutions:

You could zoom in fully to the intersection, and try to add the node as close as possible, but this might not be perfectly accurate.

Or

If you need it to be at the exact intersection, a work around is to duplicate the path on top, then also select the other line, and do Path > Cut Path to perform a boolean operation. This operation will consume the top path.  Then you can select the two end nodes of the two segments and join them.


in the gitlab issue one comment suggests to double click without hovering the selected path when the snap indicator is on the intersection.
This works.. at least kind of consistently for me!

@sourapple - yes, not very user friendly though. Perhaps I just haven't fully understood it.  But if it works for you, I'm glad it helped.

@sourapple - I just tried again, and it did work!!
